# Clarification for boxes, box tree and fragment tree

Tags: css, w3c

I am having trouble understanding the [term "box" as defined in *CSS Display 3 § 1*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#box), and when it belongs to the "box tree" or "fragment tree". I'm asking for clarification of these aspects.

In short, **my current understanding** is:

A so-called box tree reflects the document tree after considering the CSS and canvas; one box corresponds (should correspond?) to one element. That box tree is then used for rendering.

But not all boxes are (for some reason) part of that box tree.

---

Here is (vaguely) how I learned about the terms, with **confusions in bold**:

As defined in [CSS Display 3 § 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#intro), the *box tree* consists of *boxes*, and is "an intermediary structure" "[representing] the formatting structure of the rendered document (tree)".

Further, "each element (...) generates zero or more boxes as specified by [its] display property", one of which will be the element's principal box.

[CSS Inline 3 § 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#model) mentions that a *root inline box* will also be generated (for this layout), which I presume is the generated principal box and therefore part of the box tree.

It then goes on to explain that *inline boxes* (i.e. inline-level content) can be fragmented and split across *line boxes*. Though according to [CSS Inline 3 § 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#line-boxes), **line boxes are not considered part of the box tree, but clearly named "box"**.

More specifically I read that paragraph as:

> Line boxes are "like column boxes in multi-column layout": Fragmentation containers.

To me this reads (by extension) as follows: **Fragmentation container are *boxes* but not part of the *box tree***, but are again clearly named "box". (To my understanding) this interpretation of that paragraph is the only one under which column boxes too wouldn't be considered part of the box tree.

I was also told that [fragments](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-3/#fragment) are not part of the box tree either; this seems intuitive due to their different name. I was told that they are instead part of a so-called *fragment tree*.

Trying to learn more about the fragment tree, I found [W3 Minutes](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-houdini/2015Mar/0007.html) that used **"box tree" as an umbrella term for both box tree and fragment tree**, but found **no mention of "fragment tree" in the CSS specifications**. Perhaps the(se) W3 Minutes are the wrong place to search due to age (and possibly due to being related to CSS Houdini?).

According to this "collection of interesting ideas" for [CSS Houdini's Box Tree API](https://drafts.css-houdini.org/box-tree-api/), a box can have zero or more fragment trees depending on fragmentation ([CSS Break 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-4/)) and pseudo-elements. But previously **I thought the box tree and fragment tree were separate trees**, but according to this they are linked.

Comment: It does seem that the term "box" is polluted in the CSS specs, probably for historic reasons. CSS 3 cleans it up a bit, but yes line boxes, column boxes and page boxes are not "boxes" in the sense that boxes have paddings, borders, and margins, or are objects of the box tree. My own understanding of the fragment tree is too hazy to really explain in an answer, but _approximately_, the mental model I work to is that the fragment tree is the output of applying layout to the box tree. It should be noted though that some box fragmentation occurs before layout.